# Adding Double Variables in C doesn't gives decimals on print

Tags: c, printf, double, precision

I am a newbie in c.
If I try to print the sum of two double variables with 4.0 and 10.0, like:

```
printf("%lf", b+d); //b = 4.0 , d = 10.0
```

, the print isn't 14.0, it's 14 without decimals.

What should I do now?

Comment: Are you looking for exactly one digit after the decimal point under all circumstances?  For instance, what do you expect to be printed when `b` = 1.0 and `d` = 0.25?

Comment: That is strange: I would expect to see `14.000000` using the typical default of 6 decimal places.

Comment: The C standard requires `%lf` to print a `double` value with 6 decimal places, as @WeatherVane suggested.  Depending on the value printed, that might result in `14.000000` or `0.000014` or `0.000000` or `14000000000000000000.000000`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
printf( "%.1f", b + d );
```

the precision specifier (in the example above its value is `1`) after the point specifies the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point.